# Wildcard characters sql only alphabet characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I need to create a rule only for alphabet characters

i used the following  Wildcard character sequences but didn't work !

> LIKE '[A-Za-z]'
>
> LIKE 'a-z'
>
> LIKE 'A-Za-z'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Double negative like

```
WHERE
  SomeCol NOT LIKE '%[^a-z]%'
```

Ignoring the first NOT, this means "match any character *not* in the range a to z".

Then, you reverse using the first NOT which means "don't match any character *not* in the range a to z"

Edit, after comment

`LIKE '%[a-z]%'` means "find any single character between a-z. So `111s222` is matched for example because `s` matches in this like.

Comment: thanks gbn again for ur great help :D but why cant we have lyc this '%[a-z]%' without nested not !

Comment: Because if there is any (even one) alphabetic character, then it will match. It does not matter if there is a non alphabetic character. gbn's answer is the best one you can get.

Comment: like '%[a-z]%' is actually find any string contain a-z